Seinfeldisms in O.R
Let's see how well O.R. people can laugh at themselves and their profession. The resulting self-reflection and introspection might make them better at O.R.
If Jerry Seinfeld were an O.R. guy, what observations would he make about the everyday trivial, mundane, and absurd things in O.R.? O.R. practitioners, academics, students, it's all fair game.
Did you ever notice that ... ?
What is the deal with ...?
Does anyone actually believe that ...?
Like I'm really going to ...
I don't do ..., not that there's anything wrong with that.

Let's see who's master of the O.R. comedy and sarcasm domain.
I hope the posted answers will be real ... and spectacular.

Is this on topic for O.R.? The form of the question seems at odds with the general Stack Exchange format, but I'm not familiar with O.R..

@Tashus It might be more of a "wiki" than a "question", and I'm sure there will be someone who is scandalized by its frivolity, but so far it seems fairly popular. Also, the OR community can be a bit more relaxed than the general SE community, since we are not prone to flame wars.

Sites like Mi Yodeya (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) allow 'funny' questions to be asked at certain times of year. They have to be clearly marked as such. Ultimately, it's down to the site's community to decide what kind of non-objective questions they allow, not SE.

Did you ever notice that LP/IP experts sneer at flat-worlders while simultaneously assuming that everything is linear?

I apply ILP to some nonlinear problems, not that there's anything wrong with that, because a lot of nonlinearity can be incorporated into the input data, and hence the model.

I apply ILP to some nonlinear problems too ... after jumping up and down on the feasible region until it's sufficiently flat.

Beating down might not be required when all the nonlnearities are discrete.  Use as input data, whatever the nonlinearity comes out to for each of the discrete variable values, and voila, an ILP which captures the problem's nonlinearity.

Some of the nonlinearities I encounter are discrete, but some are blabbermouths.

Does anyone actually believe that P=NP? It’s like the ultimate academic punchline. We all write "unless P=NP" in our papers to sound smart, but how many of us are actually convinced that we’re going to solve it anytime soon?

Many results will be wrong if P = NP, so you need to add this.

What is the deal with optimization modelers who use average or most likely values in their models for what are very uncertain or highly variable items, and never give it a second thought, or if they do, think they will get the optimal solution "on average"? And you want to be my latex supply chain analyst?
Did you ever notice that some people spend a lot of money and time on big O.R. projects without getting buy-in from the management who will have to implement it, or talking to their people? What are these people thinking? I've been working the loading dock for 23 years, like I'm going to mess it up by doing what some college boy who doesn't have clue one tells me?
Does anyone actually believe that anything in the real world is Normally distributed? I mean, have you ever seen an honest to god Normal distribution in the wild, out in the tails? So yeah, let's do risk calculations for life and death situations based on the tail of a Normal distribution. That's gonna work real well. And for good measure, when there are several factors contributing to risk, let's implicitly assume they're all independent. I'm telling ya Ms. Failure Review Board chair, that bridge collapse was a one in a trillion event - my independent Normal risk model proves it.

Last paragraph earned an upvote

Did you ever notice that every name O.R. people come up for their field is straight out of the bizarro world?
What exactly is Operations Research? What brain surgeon came up with that name? What, are we all trying to figure out how to do surgery better?
And Management Science. Sorry folks, management is not a science.
And what is the deal with Analytics? That's not even a real word.

Analytics is definitely a real word... it's when you lytics your... oh wait...

In OR, where is the research part? I mean do we supervise control groups, design of experiments, survey design?
Why do OR guys talk of LP/linear models when much of the worldly relations are so non-linear?
Machine Learning / AI, whatever all, all have to real with optimizing an objective, yet OR is so outdated? Stuck with Industrial Engg?
